# Save Bitmap image to SD card - problem in API 1.5?

Tags: android, bitmap, save, sd-card

Any idea why this is not working on a HTC Hero running on Android API 1.5 ?

```
    private static void Save_to_SD (Bitmap bm, String image_name){
  
  String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  String meteoDirectory_path = extStorageDirectory + "/Weather_Belgium";
    
  OutputStream outStream = null;
  File file = new File(meteoDirectory_path, "/"+ image_name);
  try {
   outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
   outStream.flush();
   outStream.close();

   Log.i("Hub", "OK, Image Saved to SD");
   Log.i("Hub", "height = "+ bm.getHeight() + ", width = " + bm.getWidth());

  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.i("Hub", "FileNotFoundException: "+ e.toString());

  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.i("Hub", "IOException: "+ e.toString());
  }
   
 }
```

Logcat doesn't show any error and my images are normally 340x380:

> 12-19 12:06:41.035: INFO/Hub(1762): directory exists
>
> 12-19 12:06:41.035: INFO/Hub(1762): isDirectory = true
>
> 12-19 12:06:41.045: INFO/Hub(1762): OK, Image Saved to SD
>
> 12-19 12:06:41.045: INFO/Hub(1762): height = 340, width = 380
>
> 12-19 12:06:41.055: INFO/Hub(1762): OK, Image Saved to SD

When I then browse my SD card and take a look at my saved images, these are saved as "Invalid Image" 48 octets images !?

What's happening ?

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="4" />

  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

EDIT :
it looks like this code is working properly for PNG, JPG images but the problem has to do with the fact that my images are GIF images initially (downloaded from the web).

Comment: What does '"Invalid Image" 48 octets images' mean? BTW, you should call `mkdirs()` somewhere in there to make sure your directory exists, though I suspect this is unrelated to your problem.

Comment: it looks like this code is working properly for PNG, JPG images but the problem has to do with the fact that my images are GIF images initially (downloaded from the web). So, if someone would have a snippet of code to transform my gif images to png or jpg before saving to SD, it would make the trick ...

Comment: @CommonsWare I call mkdirs() before this code, this is not the problem. I mean by "Invalid Image" that this is the image I see if I Edit it with any image Editor like IrfanView and the likes ... the problem happens only with GIF images ? Would anyone have a working example of code that loads a GIF image from the web and saves it on the SD card (API 1.5 - SKD Version 3) ?

Comment: have you got solution for this???  I have the same problem ..