# How to Save Captured Images from Camera to specific Folder

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, save, media

I'm Looking for forward of Creating an Camera app that will provide an option to where to save a file as soon as the user launches an app.
They can either should be able to create a New Folder and rename it or either they can select the existing direcotry and when click Ok..

It would now open Camera to capture the images.

I found a hundreds tutorials on How to make an camera app and save to an destination folder and I sucessfully created  them too but nowhere I could find How to change the storage directory with Onclick inside app such that it will open a file manager and user could select the desired Destination.

Any help will be really really helpful.

Here is the some of links I tried.

[How to save images from Camera in Android to specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266572/how-to-save-images-from-camera-in-android-to-specific-folder)

[Android - Save images in an specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010739/android-save-images-in-an-specific-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[saving pictures taken by camera in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214321/saving-pictures-taken-by-camera-in-android-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I answered this question try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969072/android-save-images-to-specific-folder-in-the-sd-card/45479979#45479979

Comment: @Firdosh Thanks for help...I was looking for to add a button when clicked will open file manager and will allow user to create new folder or choose existing directory and once done then will take to the another activity where camera takes picture and will now all picture will be saved to folder just selected or created.....how can I achieve it??